# Creating a dynamic sized OR query using Sunburnt+Solr

Tags: python, solr, sunburnt

I'm trying out the python Solr interface Sunburnt , and I've come across a little problem I can't seem to figure out. From my search field, I want to accept an arbitrary number of words which I put in an array (e.g. "Music 'Iron Maiden'" -> ['Music', 'Iron Maiden']. This I've figured out (using shlex).

The problem is that Sunburnt syntax for ORing terms is

```
    response = si.query(si.Q(tag = 'Music') | si.Q(tag = 'Iron Maiden'))
```

How can I iterate over my searchword list and end up with something like the above? Or is there any other way of doing it that I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you really want to do is this:

```
query = si.query()

for word in words:
    query |= si.Q(word)
```

or, as a one-liner

```
query = reduce(operator.or_, [si.Q(word) for word in words])
```

Comment: the bottom suggestion is cleaner, imo

Comment: The first suggestion fails like so:

    TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |=: 'SolrSearch' and 'LuceneQuery'

but the second suggestion works well.

Comment: 'LuceneQuery' object has no attribute 'sort_by'
if I try sort_by after forming the similar query as mentioned above, sort_by fails. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Can you iterate over your array and construct the query expression?

Generally something similar to

```
expr=""
for word in words:
    expr = expr + "si.Q(tag =" + word + ") |"

response = si.query(expr[:-1]); #to remove the dangling "|" character
```

Comment: I'm quite sure I can't, considering that the parameters aren't given as a string, but rather as query objects.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! The `eval()` function was the key:

```
words = shlex.split(request.args.get('q', ''))

qrystr=""
for word in words:
    qrystr = qrystr + "si.Q(title_s = '*" + word.replace("\0", "") + "*') | "
    # Each word needs to be stripped of null characters for the eval to work

qrystr = qrystr[:-2]; 


results = si.query(eval(qrystr))
finalresults = results.execute()
```

Comment: the eval() function is best avoided for a number of reasons; and in this case you can manage without, see the other answer I just gave.